# Length mismatch error for python groupby plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, group-by

I want to plot mean values of a certain column in a df1 after grouping them based on the weekday. The df1 is filtered from another df based on specific column values. The first data frame contains labor data for different plane types. I filter df1 for plane type and then plot the mean of the labor data on weekly basis.The following is the code:

```
df1 = df[df['Aircraft'].str.contains('SB_A330')]

weekday = df1['Labor_Hrs'].groupby(df1.index.dayofweek).mean()

weekday.index = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']

weekday.plot(style=['-'])
```

This code only works for certain categories, I get a length mismatch error for some of them. e.g. if there are Aircraft categories 'A','B','C' and 'D', it works for 'A' & 'B" for the other I get the following error:

> "Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 7
>   elements" or
>
> "Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 7
>   elements"

The graph I get is like this :
[image: plot for category A]

Comment: Can you give an example of your dataframe? I am guessing that it is something to do with your `weekday.index` line, where the groupby is returning less than 7 days.

Comment: Yes, indeed it was with the weekday.index. reindex function fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for adding missing days for `Series` with length `7`:

```
weekday=df1['Labor_Hrs'].groupby(df1.index.dayofweek).mean().reindex(range(7), fill_value=0)
```

**Sample**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=6, freq='59H')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Labor_Hrs': range(6)}, index=rng)  
print (df1)
                     Labor_Hrs
2017-04-03 00:00:00          0
2017-04-05 11:00:00          1
2017-04-07 22:00:00          2
2017-04-10 09:00:00          3
2017-04-12 20:00:00          4
2017-04-15 07:00:00          5

weekday=df1['Labor_Hrs'].groupby(df1.index.dayofweek).mean().reindex(range(7), fill_value=0)
weekday.index = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']

print (weekday)
Mon      1.5
Tues     0.0 <-added 0 for missing 
Wed      2.5
Thurs    0.0 <-added 0 for missing 
Fri      2.0
Sat      5.0
Sun      0.0 <-added 0 for missing 
Name: Labor_Hrs, dtype: float64
```

Comment: the error is fixed now.  Thank u for the clear explanation.